# Storm cluster shutdown in Eclipse

Tags: java, real-time, distributed-computing, apache-storm

I have a problem.I understad trouble but I don't find solution.Cluster isn't shutdown,throw IOException.I/O methods not work because Windows doesn't allow temp folder.I mean this path;

> C:\Users\Mert\AppData\Local\Temp\8bbdc8e5-a753-40f3-afe0-0c2fcc1c25a0\version-2\log.1

Storm be able to delete log files for shutdown.

I tried administrator mode for Eclipse.exe and javaw.exe but it doesn't work.What can I do ?

**IO Exception stack trace:**

> exception.detailMessage -> java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file:
>   C:\Users\Mert\AppData\Local\Temp\c3c9b21b-7817-4b63-92ae-555a49743d9d\version-2\log.1
>
> exception.stackTrace -> StackTraceElement[0]  (id=130)

**Console output after run:**

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: C:\Users\Mert\AppData\Local\Temp\0edc7fc7-590f-452c-8f99-231b95a64a19\version-2\log.1
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:1390)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1044)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:977)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:1381)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1044)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:977)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:1381)
    at backtype.storm.util$rmr.invoke(util.clj:413)
    at backtype.storm.testing$kill_local_storm_cluster.invoke(testing.clj:163)
    at backtype.storm.LocalCluster$_shutdown.invoke(LocalCluster.clj:25)
    at backtype.storm.LocalCluster.shutdown(Unknown Source)
    at WordCountTopology.main(WordCountTopology.java:83)
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the IO Exception stack trace?

Comment: Was that file in use by another process?  If you restart the system does the problem persist?

Comment: @ChrisGerken No,the file is not use and I restarted the system,the problem continue.

Comment: Does he file exist? If so, what are its permissions?

Comment: @ChrisGerken How exist? I think, When topology run,file created and when topology shutdown,file can be deleted.But it is not.I mean,for example "C:\Users\Mert\AppData\Local\Temp\0edc7fc7-590f-452c-8f99-231b95a64a19\version-2\log.1" exist.

Comment: Quick fix [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658779/twitter-storm-example-running-in-local-mode-cannot-delete-file)

Answer (score 2):

nathanmarz's reply:

https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/pull/102

maybe you need a  bat for clearing log .