# Twitter storm example running in local mode cannot delete file

Tags: apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I am running the storm starter project (https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter) and it throws the following error after running for a little while.

```
23135 [main] ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn  - Thread Thread[main,5,main] died 
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: C:\Users\[user directory]\AppData\Local\Temp\a0894222-6a8a-4f80-8655-3ad6a0c10021\version-2\log.1
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:1390)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1044)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:977)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:1381)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1044)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:977)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:1381)
    at backtype.storm.util$rmr.invoke(util.clj:413)
    at backtype.storm.testing$kill_local_storm_cluster.invoke(testing.clj:164)
    at backtype.storm.LocalCluster$_shutdown.invoke(LocalCluster.clj:32)
    at backtype.storm.LocalCluster.shutdown(Unknown Source)
    at storm.starter.ExclamationTopology.main(ExclamationTopology.java:82)
```

I have tried changing the permissions of the "AppData" directory but this appears to not affect it.  This error comes up running it on the command line as well as from within eclipse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per this [File delete problem on Windows](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/pull/102), this problem still exists in storm version 0.8.2. As of now, the below workaround worked for me. You may need to comment out the `cluster.killTopology() and  cluster.shutdown()` methods, as shown below, to avoid the file deletion error.

```
 LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology("test", conf, builder.createTopology());
        Utils.sleep(10000);
       // cluster.killTopology("test");
       // cluster.shutdown();
```

Hope, this helps

Comment: I was considering this however the documentation mentions resource leaks.  Could this potentially leave threads running in the background with no way to terminate them?  Thank you for linking the github discussion that is very useful.

Comment: Yes, the threads and Java process in local mode kept running till you kill the Java process either via IDE or process explorer. Since, local mode is used for testing the development, it should be ok. I'm not sure if this problem exists in cluster mode.

Comment: Fortunately I am not trying to run a windows cluster so it should be manageable even if it does do it there. Thanks for the info!