# "Unable to delete file stormconf.ser" error while running apache storm topology

Tags: windows, apache-storm

I cloned the apache storm starter project and tried running the ExclamationTopology in local cluster mode.

getting the following exception -

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: C:\Temp1\e6ea8e8f-58fd-4290-80b1-ac34c7bb5b34\supervisor\tmp\7144480c-3faf-4719-b930-617a414a2095\stormconf.ser
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2279) ~[storm-core-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.11.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653) ~[storm-core-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.11.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535) ~[storm-core-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.11.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveDirectory(FileUtils.java:2756) ~[storm-core-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.11.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$fn__7645.invoke(supervisor.clj:1133) ~[storm-core-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.11.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:243) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$mk_synchronize_supervisor$this__7371.invoke(supervisor.clj:565) ~[storm-core-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.11.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__6939.invoke(event.clj:40) [storm-core-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.11.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780) [?:1.7.0]
24497 [Thread-18] ERROR b.s.util - Halting process: ("Error when processing an event")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Error when processing an event")
    at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:341) [storm-core-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.11.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__6939.invoke(event.clj:48) [storm-core-0.11.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.11.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780) [?:1.7.0]
```

I am using 0.11.0 version of storm. I referred few other posts - [Storm cluster shutdown in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664029/storm-cluster-shutdown-in-eclipse)

https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/pull/102

[Twitter storm example running in local mode cannot delete file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658779/twitter-storm-example-running-in-local-mode-cannot-delete-file)

but nothing worked for me. Tried commenting out the shut down part. That dint work too.

Is there any other solution to this problem? thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm having this same problem as well, did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug described in [STORM-1378](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1378). Probably related to Windows permissions.