# How to clear temp files for Apache Storm

Tags: java, apache-storm

Is there is any way to clear Storm temp files which is created under `c:/windows/temp/` through java Api or some thing else? As the Storm documentation says, at the time of shut-downing the storm cluster, it will clear the temp files (though It has a bug while deleting the temp files [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664029/storm-cluster-shutdown-in-eclipse)). But in my application I wont call the shutdown method. The storm service will be in running state throughout the life cycle. For zookeeper, clearing temp files will be like

`java -cp zookeeper.jar:log4j.jar:conf org.apache.zookeeper.server.PurgeTxnLog <dataDir> <snapDir> -n <count>`

I need similar to that one to delete the storm temp files in a **safer manner**. Since my temp size exceeds to 2 GB. Any way to achieve this or any solution has been `prescribed from Apache Storm` regarding to clear temp files?